# How to best detect certain exceptions?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

First of all: StackOverflow tells me that the question is subjective, which it is not.

I have this code:

```
try {
    // Some I/O code that should work fine, but might go weird
    // when the programmer fails or other stuff happens...
    // It will also throw exceptions that are completely fine,
    // such as when the socket is closed and we try to read, etc.
} catch (Exception ex) {
    String msg = ex.getMessage();
    if (msg != null) {
        msg = msg.toLowerCase();
    }
    if (msg == null || (!msg.equals("pipe closed") &&
                !msg.equals("end of stream reached") &&
                !msg.equals("stream closed") &&
                !msg.equals("connection reset") &&
                !msg.equals("socket closed"))) {
        // only handle (log etc) exceptions that we did not expect
        onUnusualException(ex);
    }
    throw ex;
}
```

As you can see my procedure of checking for certain exceptions works, but is VERY dirty. I'm afraid that some VMs might use other strings for the exceptions that should NOT cause the specified method to be called.

What are different solutions I could use for this problem? If I use `IOException` to check for non-unusual (lol) exceptions, I will not catch any unusual exceptions that derive from it or use it.

Answer (score 2):

For an exception that extends `IOException` (or another exception), put it in a separate `catch` statement *before* the Exception that it extends.

```
try {
    // this might throw exceptions
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) { // this extends IOException
    // code
} catch (IOException e) {
    // more code
}
```

In the above example, the code in the first statement will be executed if the exception is an instance of `FileNotFoundException`. The second one will be executed only if it is an `IOException` that is **not** a `FileNotFoundException`. Using this approach, you can deal with multiple exception types that extend each other.
You can also catch multiple types of exceptions in the same `catch` statement.

```
try {
    // even more code
} catch (IOException|ArithmeticException e) {
    // this will run if an IOException or ArithmeticException is thrown
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! While this may be part of a better solution, it's not exactly what I need. I might for example happen to catch a `NullPointerException` or any other exception, which are caused by bad programming, but for some specific exceptions I know they WILL occur due to how the used functions work. I cannot make any assumptions about what exceptions might get thrown - that code should never be called anyway if everything works fine. I can only say that `there are exceptions that are expected, all others are not`. `IOException` is used in some of these expected exceptions only.